# Как сделать появление-исчезание блока плавным?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть кнопка при клике на которую появляется и исчезает блок. Вопрос: как сделать появление-исчезание плавным?

```js
function toggle(el) {
el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
```

```css
#hidden_content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="order-call" onclick="toggle(hidden_content)">Заказать звонок</button>
<div id="hidden_content">hidden_content</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".order-call").click(() => {
  $("#hidden_content").toggle("slow");
})
```

```css
#hidden_content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="order-call">Заказать звонок</button>
<div id="hidden_content">hidden_content</div>
```